# React add class when clicked to only 1 li

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add the class `sub-menu-open` to a `li` when its clicked which will then open a submenu. however the `li`'s are dynamically generated and theres about 6 of them. When i click on an `li` its successfully adding the class to the `li` however its adding the class to all the `li`'s now just the one clicked. Can yall help me figure out how to get the class to only stick the the `li` thats clicked?

```
    const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
    
    const toggleClass = () => {
        setActive(!isActive);
    };
    
    return (
        <>
            {menus.map((menuItem, i) => {
                return (
                    <li className={"mobile-menu-item menu-item-has-children" + (isActive? ' sub-menu-open': null)} onClick={toggleClass}>
...
```

Comment: it must be only one li active at a time, or each li must be independent and we could have multiple active ones?

Comment: @buzatto no only one menu item (`li`) should be active at a time

Comment: ok then you just need to modify @moshfiqrony answer at toggle to `setActive(i => i === index ? null : i)`

Comment: @buzatto that does not work, how is `setActive` inside the `onClick` event getting `i`

Comment: it does work. `setState` can take a callback function and `i` here is the currentState. actually you can rename it to `isActive` or whatever you think is best.

Comment: actually it should be `ìndex` the return value from ternary operator: `setActive(isActive => isActive === index ? null : index)`

Comment: @buzatto now that works! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `li`

```
<li 
    className={"mobile-menu-item menu-item-has-children" + (
        isActive == i
        ? ' sub-menu-open'
        : null
    )} 
    onClick={() => toggleClass(i)}>
```

Then update the function like bellow

```
const toggleClass = (index) => {
    setActive(index);
};
```

Now update the state like bellow

```
const [isActive, setActive] = useState(null);
```

Comment: this is a great solution however now when i click on the active `li` it wont remove the `sub-menu-open` class

Comment: Just check the current value of your isActive state inside toggleClass function. If the passed index and current value are same then assign null else assign the value to the state.